# LWJGL 2.9.0 GL20.glUniformMatrix4 causes random stuttering

Tags: java, performance, lwjgl, opengl-3

I am running renderer in a separate thread at 60FPS (16ms).

Following code produces random stuttering ...

```
long testTime = System.nanoTime();
GL20.glUniformMatrix4(
    GL20.glGetUniformLocation(getProgram(), "projectionMatrix"),
    false,
    matrix4fBuffer // holds projection matrix
);
testTime = System.nanoTime() - testTime;
if (testTime > 1000000) {
    System.out.println("DELAY " + (testTime / 1000000) ); // 22-30ms
}
```

GL20.glUniformMatrix4 call randomly takes around 22-30ms (every 10s, 30s, 45s, ...) which causes random slowdown (stuttering). Normally it takes 0ms (couple of nanoseconds).

I am testing with only one object being rendered (using programmable pipeline - shaders, OpenGL >= 3.3).

Other pieces of this example:

```
getProgram() // simply returns integer

// This is called before GL20.GLUniformMatrix4
FloatBuffer matrix4fBuffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(16);
projectionMatrix.store(matrix4fBuffer);
matrix4fBuffer.flip();
```

Any idea what is happening here?

EDIT:
I forgot to mention that I am running render and update in separate threads. I guess it could be
related with thread scheduling?

EDIT:
Okay I also tested this in single threaded environment and the problem persists ... I have also found out that other calls to glUnuformMatrix4 do not cause problems e.g.:

```
long testTime = System.nanoTime();
state.model.store(buffer);
buffer.flip();
GL20.glUniformMatrix4(
    GL20.glGetUniformLocation(shader.getProgram(), "modelMatrix"),
    false,
    buffer
);
testTime = System.nanoTime() - testTime;
if (testTime > 16000000) {
    System.out.println("DELAY MODEL" + (testTime / 1000000) );
}
```

Comment: Please verify if no full-stop GC pauses are going on, using `-verbose:gc` command line argument.

Comment: I tested it and there are no records of GC interfering ... If I increase FPS I even get more delay (at 120FPS I get 260ms of delay) ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Stop doing this:

```
GL20.glUniformMatrix4(
    GL20.glGetUniformLocation(getProgram(), "projectionMatrix"),
    [...]
```

Uniform locations do not change after you link your program, and querying anything from OpenGL is a great way to kill performance.

This particular `Get` function is particularly expensive because it uses a string to identify the location you are searching for. String comparisons are slow unless optimized into something like a trie, hash tables, etc... and the expense grows as you add more potential matches to the set of searched strings. Neither OpenGL nor GLSL defines how this function has to be implemented, but you should assume that your implementation is as stupid as they come if you are concerned about performance.

Keep a `GLint` handy for your frequently used named uniforms. I would honestly suggest writing a class that encapsulates a GLSL program object, and then subclass this for any specialization. The specialized classes would store all of the uniform locations they need and you would *never* have to query GL for uniform locations.